# Notification to commenter when @username is not employed

Tags: discussion, comment, notifications, comment-replies

I noticed this behavior.  Is it new?

In question Q:

user A posts an answer, then

user B posts a comment under the answer of A, then

user A posts $n$ additional comments *without* an @B ping, then

user B receives inbox notification of $n$ comments in question Q.

I observed this as user B.  The comments of A were not edited, so that the visible comment text is the original and one can see that it never contained an @B ping, or the username of B, or quoted text or shared keywords from the comments of B, that might have generated an automatic notice.

Does the software auto-notify when the comment discussion involves only two users, or only one user other than the answerer?

Comment: I just located the answer, I guess it is better to leave the question up, but can delete the Q and the A if that is the local procedure.

Comment: It's fine to leave it here, I think. You can even accept your answer a little later!

Comment: Further info and links on how the notification system works can be found in Hendrik Vogt's answer [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/ping-only-works-for-the-first/2078#2078).

Answer (score 7):

The answer is yes.

The needle in the 50-question haystack (the intersection of [comments] and [notifications] on meta.stackoverflow) is a link inside one of those questions:

[Micro-refinement to notifications for comments of others posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts)

where this suggestion was marked as implemented on March 8, 2011:

> If a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person should be notified when the author comments even if '@user' is not specified

Comment: The linked post appears in the stackoverflow meta in a third category, [comment-replies], which is smaller than [comment] but not a subset.