# Can a user who made an edit be pinged

Tags: support, comment, notifications, comment-replies

I know that using @*username* in a comment I can ping people who were "engaged in the post", which includes:

- The poster (IIRC he is pinged even without @*username* ).
- Someone who wrote some of the comments.

Some more details on how pings work can be find e.g. [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/notification-to-commenter-when-username-is-not-employed) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4033/several-user-in-the-comment).

What about if some user edited the post, but did not post any comments. There are situations where it would be good to get his attention. (In particular if there is need to explain to the user that his edit was - for some reason - redundant, unwanted or inappropriate. Or if someone want to explain, how the user could have improved his edit.) Would @*username* in a comment work in such situation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can notify anyone who edited a post using the `@user` syntax, [see this post on Meta.SO for more details about the notification system that you really don't want to know](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/151385).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to search for such questions at meta.SO, but somehow I missed this one. The post you linked seems to be really detailed.

Comment: It may be worth editing this answer to mention that `@-notifying` editors works, but their names don't autocomplete. (While you're at it, correct the spelling of *than* (and give MSE its new name).)

Comment: Sorry for the edit, I think I misread the phrase in your link.